# Unhandled exception at 0x7725D4F2 (ntdll.dll) in App.Windows.exe: 0xC0000135: Unable to Locate DLL

Tags: c++, dll, cocos2d-x

When I try to build my cocos2dx project for win8.1 platform, I have an exceptions "Unhandled exception at ...". Previously I successfuly build project for Win32, IOS and Android without any errors. I check all simular posts on stackoverflow and apply it in my project (in most cases its already was applyed in it), but I still have an error. Another problem, that my project too big (about 700 *.h and *.cpp) and I can't place code here. Can anybody give me advice how to solove this issue?

Comment: It is a simple "file not found" error.  If you have no idea whatsoever what file could be missing then use SysInternals' Process Monitor.  Towards the end of the trace, just before the program falls over, you'll see it searching for the DLL and not finding it.

Comment: all DLL loaded successful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trouble was in phtread.lib, witch have some compatibility problems with win8.1, but works fine with other platforms. So I just removed it using from my project.